# TF loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm encountering an issue during training where the loss becomes NaN, and the accuracy remains at 0.0. I've tried to troubleshoot the problem, but I'm seeking advice on potential causes and solutions.

The `load_images_and_labels` method reads image and label data from the given folder and JSON file. For each image, it extracts grayscale representations, associated category labels, and bounding box coordinates from the JSON annotations, organizing them into NumPy arrays for further use in machine learning tasks.

```
def load_images_and_labels(folder_path, json_path):
    with open(json_path, 'r') as json_file:
        label_data = json.load(json_file)

    image_data = []
    labels = []
    boxes = []

    for image_info in label_data["images"]:
        image_id = image_info["id"]

        # Construct the full path to the file
        filename = image_info["file_name"]
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

        img = cv2.imread(image_path)

        img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Extract all labels and bounding boxes based on the image_id from the JSON data
        image_annotations = [item for item in label_data["annotations"] if item["image_id"] == image_id]

        # Check if there are annotations for the image
        if image_annotations:
            for annotation in image_annotations:
                # Extract label and bounding box information
                image_label = annotation["category_id"]
                bbox = annotation["bbox"]

                # Add the image, label, and bounding box to the arrays
                image_data.append(img_grey)
                labels.append(image_label)
                boxes.append(bbox)

    # Convert the lists to NumPy arrays
    image_array = np.array(image_data).astype('float32')
    label_array = np.array(labels)
    box_array = np.array(boxes).astype('float32')

    return image_array, label_array, box_array
```

The shapes of the methode are fitting to what i expect.
In the following you can see my method to train the model. But my output looks like this:

```
Epoch 1/10
112/112 [==============================] - 4s 15ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 2.8035e-04
Epoch 2/10
112/112 [==============================] - 2s 15ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
112/112 [==============================] - 2s 15ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
112/112 [==============================] - 2s 15ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

```
input_image = Input(shape=(400, 400), name='image_input') 
input_bbox = Input(shape=(4,), name='bounding_box_input')  

# Flachklopfen des Bildes
flatten_image = Flatten()(input_image)

merged_input = Concatenate()([flatten_image, input_bbox])

x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(merged_input)
output_layer = Dense(28, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_image, input_bbox], outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# training
model.fit({'image_input': train_images, 'bounding_box_input': train_boxes}, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

I've already considered the following:

1. Checking data and labels for correctness.
   [proof can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ln0C.png)
2. Normalizing pixel values in the images. Like: `train_images = train_images / 255.0`

Comment: I've integrated a new dataset with bounding boxes for enhanced accuracy, but i still get the same errors. Feel free to ask if you need more details.

Comment: in the meantime i think the problem is that i am using the wrong or incorrect training model

Comment: seems like i have fixed it, i am now using a pre-trained model called 'MobileNetV2' when training. This is particularly good because it is not so power hungry. so my ram usage remains very low. Furthermore, it seems that I made a small mistake with the boxes.

Comment: if you consider using the 'modelnetv2' please note that the input shape of the data must be adjusted to `input_shape = (224, 224, 3)`.